# How to parse this "31/10/13" to Oracle date in Java

Tags: java, sql, oracle, hibernate

I make an application based on hibernate,
I just wanna ask,
How to parse this "31/10/13" to Oracle date in Java, 
before this, I've try this method

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf1 = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
Date log_date = sdf1.parse(tgl1);
```

it works, but when I try to make a simple query to search data like this

```
select * from coreservice where log_date='31-OCT-13';
```

but I got `no data found` in result....

Any help will be pleasure :)

Comment: You want, ToDate method `TO_DATE('31/OCT/2013','dd/mon/yyyy')`

Comment: @Jayamohan that's great, that is in database script side.. but how I parse that string in java side

Comment: @Jayamohan thanks jaya, I just add too much 'y' in my parse format :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use oracle to_date functionin your query  as  follows:

```
select * from coreservice where log_date = to_date('31-OCT-2013','dd/mon/yyyy');
```

Comment: This should better be to_date('31-OCT-2013', 'dd-mon-yyyy', 'NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE=AMERICAN'). Otherwise it would fail in case language settings in the database don't match the months abbreviations.

Comment: to avoid nls issues you can use `DATE '2013-10-31'`